# Embedded db not starting with bolt connector (neo4j 3.2.0)

Tags: clojure, neo4j, embedded-resource, connector, bolts-framework

I am trying to create and use an embedded Neo4j instance in a clojure app. Following the documentation in [Neo4j API guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded), I was able to create following code:

```
(defn make-embedded-db
[path]
(let [factory (GraphDatabaseFactory.)]
    (-> (.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder factory path)
        (.loadPropertiesFromFile "resources/neo4j.conf")
        (.newGraphDatabase))))
```

I am importing the following libraries:

```
(:import [java.io ByteArrayInputStream ByteArrayOutputStream]
         [org.neo4j.graphdb Direction
                            GraphDatabaseService
                            Node
                            Relationship
                            RelationshipType
                            Transaction]
         [org.neo4j.graphdb.factory GraphDatabaseFactory])
```

I have bolt enabled in the conf file as follows:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
```

When I execute the `make-embedded-db` function I get the following error:

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
>   /path/to/graphdb, compiling:(form-init7747172741153885056.clj:1:9)

If I disable bolt connector in config - it seems to work fine. My main motivation to enable bolt connector is that I can connect a neo4j browser to visualize and explore the graphdb.

I came across posts for previous versions of neo4j embedded having similar issues that were resolved by using [WrappingNeoServerBootStrapper](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html) which has been deprecated. Has anyone run into this issue and point me in the right direction.

**EDITED**
I was getting the above error when assigning the embedded db instance to a global var like this

```
(def db (make-embedded-db (io/file "resources/data/graphdb")))
```

However just calling the function itself i.e.

```
(make-embedded-db (io/file "resources/data/graphdb"))
```

gave the actual error:

> VerifyError class org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name overrides final method equals

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a quick google of the error suggested there might be multiple paths to bouncycastle included in classpath - checking the debug.log in the graphdb folder actually confirmed this. I was including incanter in the same project and it was also adding it's own path for bouncycastle thus causing this issue. Removing it solved the issue.